# Javascript Getting Span Contents Upon Mouse Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml, html

I have the following markup that I am applying the succedding Javascript to in order to produce a tooltip, the problem is I am trying to set the contents of the tooltip to the contents of the span.

I cannot figure out a way of doing this without 500 different `document.get` etc...

**Basically I want to know:** In the `showTooltip` function, how can I get the contents of the span dynamically?

**Markup:**

```
<ul class="exec-List">
                    <li>
                        <img src="file:///C|/Users/tsujp/Documents/Everything/Adobe Projects/DW/KCC/Website/V8/src/committee/mirae.png" /> 

                        <span class="tooltip-span">Conten2t</span>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="file:///C|/Users/tsujp/Documents/Everything/Adobe Projects/DW/KCC/Website/V8/src/committee/mirae.png" /> 

                        <span class="tooltip-span">Content55</span>

                    </li>
                </ul>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var changeTooltipPosition = function(event)
{
  var tooltipX = event.pageX - 8;
  var tooltipY = event.pageY + 8;
  $('div.tooltip').css({top: tooltipY, left: tooltipX});
};

function showTooltip(event/*, index, el*/)
{
    /*alert( $(this).parent(this).get(0).tagName );*/

    $('div.tooltip').remove();
    $('<div class="tooltip">/* + tooltip_text +*/ </div>')
        .appendTo('body');
    changeTooltipPosition(event);
};

var hideTooltip = function()
{
   $('div.tooltip').remove();
};

$('span').each(function()
{
    if( $(this).hasClass( 'tooltip-span' ) )
    {                       
        //tooltip_text = $(el).html();

        $(this).parent(this).bind(
        {           
            mousemove : changeTooltipPosition,
            mouseenter : showTooltip/*( HOW DO I PASS 'EVENT' HERE)*/,
            mouseleave: hideTooltip
        });
    }
});
```

});

Comment: `$(this).html()` I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select on `$('.tooltip-span', this)` and take the `text()`

```
function showTooltip(event/*, index, el*/)
{
    var text = $('.tooltip-span', this).text();
    /*alert( $(this).parent(this).get(0).tagName );*/

    $('div.tooltip').remove();
    $('<div class="tooltip">' + text + '</div>')
        .appendTo('body');
    changeTooltipPosition(event);
};
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uTJUb/)